# P/Invoke with setting locale in Linux with Mono

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke

I am currently writing a wrapper for a C library. This library reads text files for internal operations.

My problem is now, that somehow this library reads the text files dependant on my locale, which is wrong. It should read the files with locale "C", especially numbers. On Windows with .NET the files are read correctly, using a simple C application, these files are also read correctly.

The C# application should run with the default locale, only the unmanaged methods should be called with locale C. Is there a way to accomplish that, possibly with an attribute on the unmanaged method?

Comment: Tried to set locale explicitly via environment variable (set LC_ALL and\or LANG variables to "C") before calling into your C library?